# How do I restore "compile" when double clicking my hxml files?

Tags: haxe, hxml

I have opened an hxml file with notepad, keeping "always use this app..." checked by accident. Cannot run hxml files anymore.

I have tried reinstalling haxe and opening the file with haxe.exe and haxelib.exe as found in the haxe folder in HaxeToolkit. As google held no answer, I'm asking here.

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on hxml-file, select "Open With" submenu -> and select "Choose another app" there:
https://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/open-with-menu-windows-10.png
Choose "haxe.exe" in opened list and select "Always use this app..." and then click "OK". If there is no "haxe.exe" then click on "Look for another app":
https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Windows-10-My-Capture-0003.png
and find "haxe.exe" on you PC (in my case it was in "C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe" folder)

Comment: Cannot accept this as an answer since it's something I already tried. As mentioned in the question's body.

Comment: I want "compile" back. Also, opening with haxe.exe through the open with dialog doesn't do anything but make a cmd window appear for a fraction of a second.

However: Hm, it seems that once haxe.exe is set as the default, double clicking the file does compile my project. Wish I could get "compile" back instead of "open" but whatever, it works. Maybe I imagined things.